# functions between metric spaces: How much freedom do I have, when I choose the metrics to proof continuity of a function? $\epsilon-\delta$-criteria

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

Let $X, Y$ be metric spaces with the metrics $d_X: X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $d_Y: Y\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

A funtion $f:X\rightarrow  Y$ is continious at the point $a$, if for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $\delta >0$ such that for every $x\in X$:
$d_X(x,a)<\delta \Rightarrow d_Y(f(x),f(a))<\epsilon $

Assuming that the metrics $d_X$ and $d_X'$ are equivalent..
The same assumption for $d_Y$ and $d_Y'$.

Let $(X,d_X),(X,d_X'),(Y,d_Y)$ and $(Y,d_Y')$ be metric spaces.

If I showed that $f$ is continuous at a point $a\in X$ with respect to $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, I think that I can conclude that $f$ is also continuous in the metric spaces:

1. $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y')$
2. $(X,d_X')$ and $(Y,d_Y)$
3. $(X,d_X')$ and $(Y,d_Y')$

Reasoning: A funtion $f:X\rightarrow  Y$ is continious at the point $a$, if for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $\delta >0$ such that:
$x\in U_{\delta,d_X}(a) \Rightarrow f(x)\in U_{\epsilon ,d_Y}(f(a))$

Case 2.)
The metrics $d_X$ and $d_X'$ are equivalent, so $U_{\delta,d_X}(a)$ is also open in $(X,d_X')$, so that one can find a $\delta'>0$ such that $U_{\delta',d_X'}(a)\subset U_{\delta,d_X}(a)$.
$x\in U_{\delta',d_X'}(a)\Rightarrow x\in U_{\delta,d_X}(a)\Rightarrow f(x)\in U_{\epsilon ,d_Y}(f(a))$

Case 1.)
Let $\epsilon >0$ be given and the implication $x\in U_{\delta,d_X}(a) \Rightarrow f(x)\in U_{\epsilon ,d_Y}(f(a))$ be true for a $\delta>0$.

The metrics $d_Y$ and $d_Y'$ are equivalent.

Here it is harder for me to argue for this implication:
$x\in U_{\delta,d_X}(a)\Rightarrow f(x)\in U_{\epsilon ,d_Y}(f(a))\Rightarrow f(x)\in U_{\epsilon ,d_Y'}(f(a))$
Because $\epsilon$ is fixed.

My main question is best explained with an example:

$$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \\
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \\ \frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$

My proof that this function is continuous in $(x,y)=(0,0)$:

I use the Euclidean metric $d_e(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $d(f(x,y),f(x',y'))=|f(x,y)-f(x',y')|$.
Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.
Choose $\delta =\epsilon$, for any $(x,y)\neq 0$ with $d_e(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ follows:

$$ |f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=|f(x,y)|=|\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}|=2|xy||\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}|\leq |x^2+y^2||\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}|=|x|\leq |x|\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta =\epsilon$$

I know that every norm $q$ induces a metric and every norm in $\mathbb{R^n}$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is equivalent.

Since $d_e$ is induced by the Euclidean norm, can I now conclude that $f$ is continuous at the point $(0,0)$ in every metric space with an metric $d_N: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto q(x,y) $ that is induced by a norm $q$ ???

So if I need to proof that $f$ is continuous with respect to the metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, I could just show that $f$ is continuous with respect to the metric spaces $(X,d_X')$ and $(Y,d_Y')$, if $d_Y',d_Y$ and $d_X,d_X'$ are equivalent?

As an example I could have used the Manhattan norm to proof that $f$ is continuous with respect to $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_e)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)$:

Choose $\delta =\epsilon$, for any $(x,y)\neq 0$ with $d_1(x,y)=|x|+|y|<\delta$ follows:

$$ |f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=|f(x,y)|=|\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}|=2|xy||\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}|\leq |x^2+y^2||\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}|=|x|\leq |x|+|y|<\delta =\epsilon$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$, and for a function $f:X\to Y$ and a point $x_0\in X$, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if whenever $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset X$ satisfies $\lim_n x_n=x_0$, then $\lim_n f(x_n)=f(x_0)$. **This holds for metric spaces, but not all topological spaces.**

Equivalent metrics have the same convergent sequences, so it's easy to see using the sequential criterion from the previous paragraph that continuity of $f:(X,d)\to (Y,\rho)$ at $x_0\in X$ is equivalent to continuity of $f:(X,d')\to (Y,\rho')$ at $x_0$, where $d,d'$ are equivalent on $X$ and $\rho, \rho'$ are equivalent on $Y$. If the preceding paragraph holds for sequences which are $d'$-convergent in $X$ and $\rho'$-convergent in $Y$, then it also holds for sequences which are $d$-convergent in $X$ and $\rho$-convergent in $Y$, since $d$-convergence is the same as $d'$-convergence in $X$ and $\rho$-convergence is the same as $\rho'$-convergence in $Y$.

If you want to prove the equivalence using only the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ condition without using the sequential characterization, you'll want to start with an $\epsilon>0$. By equivalence of $\rho$ and $\rho'$, there exists $\epsilon'>0$ such that $U_{\epsilon',\rho'}(f(x_0))\subset U_{\epsilon,\rho}(f(x_0))$.  By $d'$-$\rho'$ continuity, there exists $\delta'>0$ such that $f(U_{\delta',d'}(x_0))\subset U_{\epsilon',\rho'}(f(x_0))$. By equivalence of $d$ and $d'$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $U_{\delta,d}(x_0)\subset U_{\delta',d'}(x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are already done!
There is some nested ball of radius r:
$$U_{r ,d_{Y}}(f(a)) \subset U_{\epsilon ,d'_{Y}}(f(a)) $$
So by continuity of $f$ at $a$ take the appropriate $\delta$.